# how to make a file that will open visual studio code and run the script

Tags: executable

I'm new to coding and Python and I've managed to create a script that takes two excel reports, manipulates the data, and creates a customized excel report for the client. I currently just hit Shift+Enter to run the script when I need to but I want to create a file in a folder that I can just click and it would just run the script. This would let my other teammates that don't code be able to just run the script without looking at the code.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to convert the script into an exe but I think I realize that the script isn't meant for an .exe file. I tried converting the .py file to .exe with auto-py-to-exe and Pyinstaller but nothing runs when i click on the .exe file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I also tried to open the folder path on VS and see if I can right click and select "add as startup item" but I don't have that selection.

Comment: try with a .bat script that calls the python script

Comment: how are you calling pyinstaller, I think you need to elaborate more on your project structure, etc...

Comment: Thanks Vland! I just created a simple .bat file and it worked!

@echo off
"C:\Users\dhuang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe" "C:\Users\dhuang\Documents\Dennis_Python_Scripts\test.py"
pause